# Apache+Passenger - Apache running; but not responding to requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, apache2, passenger

**Background**

I'm running a Ruby on Rails application that has to serve a lot of static files as well.

My setup currently is:

Debian Linux Lenny 5.0
 Apache 2.2.9
 Passenger 2.2.10

**The problem**

Everything runs fine. I see apache process spinning up, passenger instances get created and everything works fast and snappy.

Then, after some time Apache does not respond to requests any more. Clients do get a connection and are "waiting for a response", but none comes.

I cannot manually reproduce this problem. Sometimes it occurs a few hours after a restart, other times it takes a few days to happen. Here's what I found:

Apache process are up; Passenger is there, but it does not have any instances spun up (probably because instances die after a period of inactivity)

No error messages or problems in /var/log/syslog, /var/log/messages, not in apache's access and errors logs, not in my Rails production log. Nothing.

When I stop and start apache everything is back to normal.

Does any one have any clues what's happening here? And how it can be resolved?

Comment: As an added note; We're running mpm_worker, because of Passenger. This is set to MaxClients of 200 by default. We've already upped this to 1000 (and ServerLimit to 50). But we're still having the same issues.

Comment: when it happens, Will you have changes in access_log if you try to send request? and what will be if you turn-off passenger when it happend. or just graceful restart http

Comment: You might want try nginx w/passenger to determine whether the problem is in Apache or passenger.

Comment: What your passenger global queue like? I used to run across these problems. The requests were piling up on the global queue.

Comment: just do a version downgrade and test it . I had a same problem i just downgraded Passenger version its got resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to an enormous load on static files we decided to host static files on separate server (later Amazon S3+CloudFront) for performance reasons.

My current guess is that Apache couldn't cope with the large number of requests on static files *and* also doing Passenger. The current setup is Nginx+Unicorn for the Rails application and S3+CloudFront for static files.